# unknown table in my database of Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

When I did a `select * from tab` in my schema, it showed all the tables along with few new tables which are not created by me. The names of the table are quit contradictory to oracle naming conventions. One of them is like `BIN$BwCyfyRPTJMKYfRpcHhiuQ==$0`.

When I tried to drop them, it gave error invalid table name. I don't understand how did they got created in the first place. This is a local database of Oracle 10g. I doubt it as Virus. Please help how to get rid of these or I ll have to format my machine.

Comment: Not relevant, but Oracle [recommends you don't use `tab`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5178.htm); why not use `user_tables`?

Answer (score 3):

Those are dropped tables that were moved to the recycle bin.

If you run

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN;
```

then those tables will go away.

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9018.htm#SQLRF01803